# Can system services change during an app's life?

Tags: android

Is it possible for a service returned by `Context#getSystemService(String name)` to change during the lifetime of an app?

I ask because I'm wondering whether it's better for a class to keep a reference to a `LocationManager`, or to keep a `Context` and repeatedly lookup the `LocationManager` when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

It may change but functionality will be same.

Keeping a reference to that service and/or keeping context reference in your class can be nullified by android system itself. Same way that service will be closed and re-opened.

Personally i would keep the reference of the service if the context is not different each time i ask for the service instance.